Moment of Hermite's function of Gaussian
Let $(N_i)_{1 \leq i \leq 2n}$ be a Gaussian vector with zero mean and covariance $C = (c_{ij})_{1 \leq i, j \leq 2n}$ and
$$E_n := \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{2n} N_i e^{-N_i^2/2}\right]$$
It is possible to have a nice formula for $E_n$ or an upper bound for $|E_n|$ ?
By "nice", I mean that it take into accout two fact:

If $c_{ij} \to 0$ for all $i, j$, then $E_n \sim c_{ii}^{2n} n!$.
It decorrelate as in the Isserlis formula:
$$e_n := \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{2n} N_i \right] = \sum_{p \in P_n^2} \prod_{(i, j) \in p} c_{i,j},$$
where $(P_n)$ denotes the set of pairing of $\{1, \dots, 2n\}$. Indeed if $c_{i_0, j} = 0$ for all $j$, then $e_n = 0$. Similarly, $e_n = 0$, if one can decompose $(N_i)$ in blocks of random variables, with one block of odd size, for which the random variables appearing in each blocks are independent of the one appearing in the others.

The expectation $E_n$ can be written, $\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{2n} \psi_1(N_i)\right]$, where $\psi_1(x) = x e^{-x^2/2}$ is the (not normalized) Hermite function. So, it may appear somewhere in the litterature.
My progresses so far are the following.

We can write $E_n = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{2n} Y_i\right]$, where $(Y_i)_{1 \leq i \leq 2n}$ is a Gaussian vector with covariance $C_1 = (I_{2n} + C^{-1})^{-1}$. Then, we can apply the Isserlis formula. However, from the expression of $C_1$ it is not clear to chek the previous point 2.
We can apply the integration by part formula for Gaussian vector. But the expression becomes quickly heavy and I don't see a clear patern appearing.

EDIT 1 (context):
I may add a little bit more context to give a more precise idea of what I am looking for and the difficulties that I am encountering. In my general problem, I want to upper bound:
$$I_n := \int_{W^{2n}} E_n(x_1, \dots, x_{2n})^2 dx_1 \dots dx_{2n},$$
where $W$ is a compact set, $E_n(x_1, \dots, x_{2n})$ is defined as previously but with $N_i = Z(x_i)$ where $Z$ is a centered stationnary Gaussian field with covariance function $f$, non-negative and compactly supported in $[-1, 1]^{2n}$. When considering $e_n(x_1, \dots, x_{2n})$ one can integrate each pair of indexes, and obtain that $i_n$ (defined as $I_n$ but with $e_n$ instead of $E_n$) is bounded by $(n!)^2 |W|^{n} E(Z(0))^{4n}$. My problem is whether we can obtain a similar bound for $I_n$.
Note that the comment of Jarosław Błasiok does not allow to bound directly $I_n$. Indeed, it provides a bound on the support of $E_n$ that make the integral scaling as $n!$. However, taking into acount the variance of $Z(0)$ makes appear an other $(n!)^2$. In the standard Isserlis formula, the variance and the support are coupled (through $c_{ij}$), that avoid the previous issue.
EDIT 2 (numerical simulations):
I did numerical simulations and it seems that $|E_n| \leq |e_n|$. Accordingly, a way to tackle the problem may be to prove that
$$f(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{2n} N_i e^{-tN_i^2/2}\right]^2,$$
is non-increasing (it may the false). It would the ok, if is it true for small $t$ (but that it quantified with respect to $c_{i, j}$ and $n$). However, $C$ has non-negative coefficients, but it is not true that $C_1$ has also non-negative coefficients, so studying the sign of $f'(t)$ is not direct.

Doesn’t your idea (1) actually solve the problem? To see that the requirement 2 is satisfied, it’s enough to observe that computing an inverse for a block diagonal matrix corresponds to inverting each block separately, or am I missing something?

Nice remark. In fact, in my general problem, $N_i = Z(x_i)$ where Z is a Gaussien field with covariance function $f$ (positive and compactly supported) and I want to integrate $E_n$ with respect to $x_1, \dots, x_{2n}$. In the "standard Isserlis case", one can integrate each pair $f(x_i - x_j)$, so we can integrate $n$ variables $x_i$. It is not clear to me if we can do the same with the idea (1). Should I add this context in the question ?

I do not understand the sentence « If $c_{ij} \to 0$ for all $i, j$, then $E_n \sim c_{ii}^{2n} n!$ ». I understand that $n$ fixed a,d the correlations vary? What is $i$ in the formula $E_n \sim c_{ii}^{2n} n!$?

Sorry, it wasn't clear. The $\sim$ was just a way to write "it should be". A better way to write it would be $|E_n| \leq C \max_i c_{ii}^{2n} n!$, for some numerical constant. Indeed, I would like to say that the scaling with respect to $n$ of $E_n$ should the one of $e_n$, i.e. the variance of $N_i$ times $n!$, if we scale each coefficient the covariance matrix $C$ by a really small factor. Due to my application with stationnary random field, I totally forgot  to add that the $N_i$ have the same distribution. So, $c_{ii} = \operatorname{Var}(N_i) =  \operatorname{Var}(N_0)$.
